# Push Notification not received when app is in foreground ios flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, cross-platform

I have integrated firebase for push notifications in flutter. If the app is in foreground I have displayed a dialog with notification details. I am receiving notifications properly in android. Also in iOS notifications are working fine in background and when device is locked. I have enabled push notifications and background fetch as well. Any solution for this? Has anybody faced such issue?

I am using this firebase plugin
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

Answer (score 0):

1. import UserNotifications in AppDelegate.
2. UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self in didFinishLaunch
3. Implement the below the method in AppDelegate.

`func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent     notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping(UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) { print("Push notification received in foreground.") completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge]) }`

Comment: Notifications are receiving. Not receiving only when app is running

Comment: Yes It will work, to show notification when app is in foreground it is required to implement UserNotification framework for iOS

Comment: Thanks. Where to call that method userNotificationCenter?

Comment: Notifications are received but it disappears from the notification tray after few seconds. I have a dialog in which is shown if there is any new notification

Comment: Not getting your scenario properly, If you want to show alert write your code to display dialogue below print statement it will work

Comment: Thanks but how will I get message details or content ?

Comment: You can store content from didReceiveRemoteNotification and use inside this method